# Oracle connection pooling - Invalid or Stale Connection found in the connection cache

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling

I see that after 1 hour of running, Oracle Connection Pool throws exceptions

" SQLException Ocurred:Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache"

Here is the properties file:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${local.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${local.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${local.password}" />
    <property name="connectionProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="includeSynonyms">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="PropertyCheckInterval">60</prop>         <!-- 1 min -->
                <prop key="ValidateConnection">true</prop>
                <prop key="MinLimit">2</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">25</prop>
                <prop key="InitialLimit">2</prop>
                <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">60</prop>         <!-- 1 min -->
                <prop key="InactivityTimeout">1800</prop>           <!-- 30 mins -->
                <prop key="AbandonedConnectionTimeout">600</prop>   <!-- 10 mins -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Can somebody tell me why this is failing after 1 hour, even though the transactions are active.

Comment: Ask your DBA if the database user has a profile with resource limits (specifically idle_time).

Comment: I was not using multi-threading and it was failing.

Comment: Also, we need to configure the num of threads to atleast the min number of connections. Otherwise the connections become stale and throw exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using multi-threading and it was failing. Also, we need to configure the num of threads to atleast the min number of connections. Otherwise the connections become stale and throw exceptions

Comment: I'm also getting this issue. Can you please tell me what you mean by implementing multi threading in this context? Is it like an attribute in the xml property? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have run into the same issue. Options of solutions are

- Oracle UCP - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/toc.htm
- Apache DBCP - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Answer (score -2):

URL should be url in the xml configuration.

Comment: I'm unable to comprehend your answer. connection was failing after 1 hour not immediately. please see my comments in the previous post for the answer

Comment: Heh yeah, I'm not sure what you're trying to say with this answer. Can you elaborate a little more?